# Exact meaning of ICMP protocol 1 port xxx unreachable in a ping exchange

Tags: networking, ping, icmp

A tcpdump of a ping session shows the following two lines:

```
IP gateway.comp.com > somehost.comp.com: ICMP redirect 10.8.0.10 to host othergateway.comp.com, length 68
IP gateway.comp.com > somehost.comp.com: ICMP 10.8.0.10 protocol 1 port 21475 unreachable, length 68
```

I understand the first message. It just tells `somehost` to not bother the main `gateway` with packets to 10.8.0.10 but rather route them right through `othergateway`.

But what does the second message mean. It comes 17ms later and seems to be related. What is `protocol 1 port XXX` in this context. What exactly is it that is unreachable? ICMP (=protocol 1) has not ports, afaik, so what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably [ICMP control message Type 3 (destination unreachable) Code 3 (Port unreachable)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Destination_unreachable)

It means there is no server process associated with that TCP or UDP port at the destination.

*"One rule of UDP is that if it receives a UDP datagram and the destination port does not correspond to a port that some process has in use, UDP responds with an ICMP port unreachable."* - from [TCP/IP Illustrated, Stevens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_Illustrated).

Why UDP? The `ping` command is traditionally implemented using ICMP echo requests but on some platforms, some tools can use other protocols. An example would be `nmap -sU`

Comment: Hmm, not convinced about the UDP theory. The `gateway` definitively gets ICMP packets form `somehost`. It does not know somebody is using `ping` on `somehost`. It only knows the packets. Why should it switch from ICMP to UDP? But then again: I am only logging ICMP. So maybe the unreachable actually refers to a UDP packet I was not logging.

Answer (score 0):

> What is `protocol 1 port XXX` in this context.

Protocol number 1 is ICMP. ICMP doesn't use ports but it uses a 16-bit identifier that is referred to as `port` here for simplicity. (Perhaps the programmer couldn't be bothered to make the distinction or users would be more confused by an `identifier` label.)

The identifier field is also used by NAT routers to map replies to the original NAT session, and of course by the local IP stack itself to route an echo reply back to the process that originated the request - very much like a transport-layer port number.